# Sort reducer key by name in combineReducers - Redux - Typescript

Tags: typescript, sorting, redux, redux-reducers

I have a lot of redux reducers which are passed into combineReducers before sending it to the store. In js, I would generally do the below and it sorts. Please note that the reducers here are dummy.

```
const reducers = {
    router: connectRouter(history),
    ...c,
    ...d,
    ...a,
}

export default combineReducers(
    Object.keys(reducers)
    .sort()
    .reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: reducers[cur] }), {})
);
```

However in typescript, if I try to the same thing, I actually run into a lot of errors.

```
export default combineReducers<RootState, RootAction>(
    Object.keys(reducers)
    .sort()
    .reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: reducers[cur] }), {})
);
```

The error is

> TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducersMapObject<RootState, PayloadAction<"@user/setCurrentUser", ADUser> | PayloadAction<"@profile/setProfile", Profile> | PayloadAction<"@client/setClients", ClientMap> | ... 81 more ... | PayloadAction<...>>'.   Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReducersMapObject<RootState, PayloadAction<"@user/setCurrentUser", ADUser> | PayloadAction<"@profile/setProfile", Profile> | PayloadAction<"@client/setClients", ClientMap> | ... 81 more ... | PayloadAction<...>>': currentUser, profile, clients, models, and 22 more.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using

```
const sortedReducers = Object.keys(reducers)
  .sort()
  .reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: reducers[cur] }), {});

export default combineReducers<RootState, RootAction>(
  sortedReducers as typeof reducers
);
```